# Exibir notificação todo dia

Tags: android

Estou querendo mostrar uma notificação todo dia no mesmo horário, eu consegui mostrar uma notificação em um horário , mais quando chega no mesmo horario de novo ela não aparece

MyActivity

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date data1 = cal.getTime();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    Date data2 = cal.getTime();
    if (data1.compareTo(data2) != 1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else {
        Log.e("Else", "Entrou");
    }
```

AlarmReceiverActivity

```
int notificationId = 001;

    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    viewIntent.putExtra("notificacao", "2");
    PendingIntent viewPendingIntent =PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setContentTitle("")
                    .setContentText("Que tal da uma olhada nas suas tarefas agora?")
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))//RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                    .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
     notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
    finish();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça o seguinte em `MyActivity`, utilizando `AlarmManager.setRepeating(...)`:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

// 24 horas em ms.
// Dica: mude o (24 * 60) para 2 e verifique se a notificação vai
// aparecer a cada 2 min, para não ter que esperar 24 horas...  
final int period = (24 * 60) * 60 * 1000; 

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), period, pendingIntent);
```

---

Certifique-se de que você declarou o serviço `AlarmReceiverActivity` no seu AndroidManifest, dentro da tag `<application>`. Exemplo: